# What does this function from Google PlusOne do?

Tags: javascript

In the following function:

```
(function() {
  var po = document.createElement('script');
  po.type = 'text/javascript';
  po.async = true;
  po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);  })
();
```

The following create a po document script object and the source is from the google plusone.js.
Then get the doucment's first script element and assign to s.  Finally insert script s before po.

My question  is what's the purpose of that function?

Comment: My guess is google doesn't want to override global variables or allow theirs to leak

Answer (score 2):

That function is called Immediately Invoked Function Expression or IIFE for short. The purpose is to enclose the code in a new scope so the variables don't leak to the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

This function dynamically inserts and loads a script onto the current page (dynamic script inclusion).

The function itself is an IIFE, which prevents the variables from being added to the global scope.

Answer (score -1):

It inserts new s script before existing script element.